# Javascript url parameters with html5 video tag not working on iphone/ipad via wifi thumb drive

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, url, parameters

I am having problem playing videos on iphone/ipad. I have multiple videos on a single page called "VideoPlayer.html" with the following script.

```js
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
  var videoId = queryObj()["V"];
  
  switch(videoId)
  {
   case "MainMovie":
     videoPlayer.src="../Videos/jude.mp4";
     break;
   case "Video2":
     videoPlayer.src="../Videos/Puma_Slidshow.mp4";
     break;
  }
 }
 
 function queryObj() {
  var result = {}, keyValuePairs = location.search.slice(1).split('&');

  keyValuePairs.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
   keyValuePair = keyValuePair.split('=');
   result[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1] || '';
  });

  return result;
 }

</script>
```

```html
<div id="container">
<video id="videoPlayer" autoplay preload="metadata" controls></video>
</div>
```

Then i got a page called "Main.html" where i am linking these videos from Videoplayer.html with the following code.

```js
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var videos = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
   videos[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
  };
 }

 function clickHandler(el) {
  window.open("VideoPlayer.html?V=" + el.target.id, "_self" );
 }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="menubar1">
 
  <a id="MainMovie" class="link">Play Movie</a>
        <a id="Video2" class="link">Scene Selection</a>
        <a href="#">Special Features</a>
 
</div>
```

It all works fine on desktop when I click the "Play Movie" the url opens up with VideoPlayer.html?V=MainMovie and plays the video in a new window. which is exactly what i want but i need this code to work on iphone/ipad as well. I am really new to JavaScript and HTML. All these videos and HTML files will be used offline.

Thanks